# rawpy/_rawpy.c: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, python, pip

I'm rebuilding my machine (14.04 LTS) and rawpy is resisting my efforts to install it.

Here is the output of `pip install rawpy`:

```
$ pip install rawpy
Downloading/unpacking rawpy
  Downloading rawpy-0.10.1.tar.gz (107kB): 107kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/rawpy/setup.py) egg_info for package rawpy

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from rawpy)
Downloading/unpacking enum34 (from rawpy)
  Downloading enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: rawpy, enum34
  Running setup.py install for rawpy
    building 'rawpy._rawpy' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_HAS_LIBRAW_CONFIG_H=1 -I/usr/local/include/libraw -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c rawpy/_rawpy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rawpy/_rawpy.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: rawpy/_rawpy.c: No such file or directory
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/rawpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Pff6SC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
  running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rawpy
copying rawpy/enhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rawpy
copying rawpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rawpy
copying rawpy/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rawpy
  running build_ext
building 'rawpy._rawpy' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rawpy
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_HAS_LIBRAW_CONFIG_H=1 -I/usr/local/include/libraw -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c rawpy/_rawpy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rawpy/_rawpy.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: rawpy/_rawpy.c: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/rawpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Pff6SC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/rawpy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/image/.pip/pip.log
root@iExam_SD_bld01_002:~/libraw#
```

Comment: Did you install the libraw development headers first?  `sudo apt-get install libraw-dev`

Comment: Yes I did: 
   " libraw-dev is already the newest version"